# Linked-in notification in Android

Tags: android, post, notifications, linkedin-api, social-media

I did linked in integration like this `https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk-auth
I am able to login in linked-In and share content, but I don't find anything related to linked in notifications. 
Can we get linked-in notification in Android. If yes so how ? Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Can you add your code and any error messages you've encountered?

Comment: I don't find any code to get Notification in Linked-In. If you have please send the link.